Verification of hmac signature from headers
I'm implementing payment on my SaaS, I use LemonSqueezy and my API is made in TS with AdonisJS, here's my problem:
When a payment is validated LemonSqueezy calls the webhook of my API with a signature key in header that looks like this: 'X-Signature', to certify that the webhook is called by LemonSqueezy I have a token and I have to verify that the token of the signature corresponds to the secret that I filled in the webhook, but I can't do this verification, their doc says:
const crypto = require('crypto');

const secret    = '[SIGNING_SECRET]';
const hmac      = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
const digest    = Buffer.from(hmac.update(request.rawBody).digest('hex'), 'utf8');
const signature = Buffer.from(request.get('X-Signature') || '', 'utf8');

if (!crypto.timingSafeEqual(digest, signature)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid signature.');
}

Je n'ai pas réussie a l'adapter a AdonisJs
Voici ce que j'ai essayé mais qui ne marche pas :
 async handle({ request }: HttpContext, next: NextFn) {
    const secret = 'secret'
    const rawBody = await getRawBody(request.request)
    console.log('rawBody', rawBody.toString('utf8'))
    const signature = request.header('X-Signature') || ''

    if (!this.verifySignature(rawBody, signature, secret)) {
      throw new Error('Invalid signature.')
    }

    await next()
  }

  private verifySignature(rawBody: Buffer, signature: string, secret: string): boolean {
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
    const digest = Buffer.from(hmac.update(rawBody).digest('hex'), 'utf8')
    const receivedSignature = Buffer.from(signature, 'utf8')
    return crypto.timingSafeEqual(digest, receivedSignature)
  }

Pour le test j'ai mis le secret en dur
